When do regression models outperform naive methods?
Case1:
I have the following task to do: Training by the consecutive 3 days to predict the each 4th day. Each day data represents one CSV file which has dimension 24x25. Every datapoints of each CSV file are pixels.
Now, I need to do that, predict day4(means 4th day) by using training data day1, day2, day3(means three consecutive days), after then calculate mse between predicted day4 data and original day4 data. Let's call it mse1.
Similarly, I need to predict the day5 (means 5th day) by using training data day2, day3, day4, and then calculate the mse2(mse between predicted day5 data and original day5 data)
I need to predict day6(means 6th day)by using training data day3, day4, day5,  and then calculate mse3(mse between predicted day6 data and original day6)
..........
And finally I want to Predict day93 by using training data day90, day91, day92,calculate mse90(mse between predicted day93 data and original day93)
I want to use Ridge regression, Linear regression and LSTM model. And we have 90 mse for each model.
Case2:
Here I am using,  is known as "the" naive forecast, or a "random walk" forecast. It is often hard to beat.
Naive approach is:
The guess for any day is simply the map of the previous day. I mean simply guess that day2 is the same as day1, guess that day3 is same as day2, guess that day4 is same as day3,....., guess that day91 is same as day90. I mean Predict next day's data using current day's data(predicted_data = current_day_data). Then calculate mse between next_day_data and current_day_data.
Results:

In case1, I observe that, It is extremely common for very simple methods(regression models) to outperform complex ones(lstm) in low data situations. This is satisfying as expected. Simple methods will be especially competitive in low data situations. "Competitive" quite simply means "lower prediction error".

In case2, we know naive method often very hard to beat, means lower MSE,  but it is outperformed by simple regression approach in case1.



My question:
We know that any simple methods works well in low amount of data(
Reference1,Reference2), since naive method is more simple methods than regression models, so question is how regression is doing well than naive? We know that naive method is often hard to beat(means it often have lower mse). But in my case I get exception.  My teacher said me that I need to dig into my data to understand that. But my question is how to do that?
In which situation would one simple regression model(in case1) outperform a naive method (in case2)? I mean, how to know specifically why one simple method outperforms another naive one on my specific dataset?

My data sample for example the day1 ,day2 ,day3 ,day4.
Each MSE is calculated this way : we have one error (more accurately called a residual): the difference between the true and predicted values. The mean squared error(MSE) would be the mean of those squared differences, and we get one per model. 

Maybe https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://ai.stackexchange.com/ would be better  place to ask?

StackExchange sites also have a limit of one question per post. If you decide to post this in a more specialized community, be sure to delete this post, and limit that post to a single question.

@GregBurghardt this question I have been trying many sites, but don't get attention, please let me try here, after getting answer in one site, I will delete another question.

@GregBurghardt also I have seen this kind of question's answered in past in this community, please let me try here.

Sure. This can be on-topic for this community too. Right now there are two close votes because it needs focus, not because it is off-topic. Can you [edit] your post to focus on a single question?

@GregBurghardt Ok.

"When one simple regression models(in case1) outperforms naive method (in case2)?" is not a question. It's an event. What about it? Please reword this question so we don't have to guess what you want.

When I ask for an edit I’m not looking for a conversation. I’m trying to improve your questions reception. Please edit.

@candied_orange I already edited the question.

“So, When one simple regression models(in case1) outperforms naive method (in case2)?” Is still not a question. I really am trying to help you. Please edit to fix this.

@candied_orange actually English isn't my native language, I am to trying fix it. Please Let me know if it's not clear.

Ok that might be something I can fix. I’ll edit. You check if it makes sense to you.

Note: I saw some discussion about the scope of this question to the site, and also about the question itself. I'll try to help with both by not going deep into the maths of each model, but rather in the general aspects that every software engineer should know.
It is not entirely true that naive methods are better or more accurate. It all depends on the method itself and how well it can adjust to the data. When trying to approximate linear data, a linear regression (or also a polynomial regression with grade 1) will fit better than a polynomial regression grade 2, even when grade 2 has more "moving parts".
Grade 2 could degenerate into grade 1 if the gradients are learned perfectly, but this almost never happens in real models. There is a reason for this: all models are approximations. This means that all models have some level of error. Think of it as a "blind spot", some kind of space in the input domain where the results predicted by the model are not perfect.
This is what your teacher meant to say when they asked you to dig into your data: look into the residuals you gathered and ask yourself what is common in the places where a model starts failing. You'll see that LSTM behaves badly near the start, middle and end (really bad) of your dataset. The naive prediction behaves better, but the residuals chart still has some bumps at the beginning and end of your graph. Ask yourself "why", what do those datapoints have in common that make the models generate wrong predictions.
This is also because all models can be seen as functions (in fact, mathematically they are):
f(data, parameters) → prediction
Of course, what makes ML models distinct from regular functions is that we don't know what the parameters for the model are -- instead, we make the model learn those parameters. Another way to say this is that we pick the parameters that reduce the error in a way that we find convenient (we pick the loss function, we pick the metric to optimize, we pick the learning mechanism, etc.) We do this based on our data, and if this sounds circular, yes, it is -- this is why ML has created so many mechanisms to avoid "cheating" and instead generalize to the parts the model hasn't seen yet. (Avoid overfitting.)
With that background, it's now easier to address your questions:

My teacher said me that I need to dig into my data to understand that. But my question is how to do that?

It depends on what your looking for. If your goal is to understand why a model behaves well or worse, look for patterns that explain the errors. For an initial exercise, looking at what a model does + the chosen parameters + the common data points where it errors out should be enough. However, know that understanding why a model behaves the way it behaves is a whole field of study called interpretability.

In which situation would one simple regression model(in case1) outperform a naive method (in case2)?

I won't go into the details of your specific model and your particular training and the particular behaviours of your data, but following what I mentioned before, here are some tips:

The naive model has no logic, it predicts that there is no variation from day n to day n+1. Since it behaves reasonably well, what does that tell you about the data?
The linear regression will pick a linear combination of your last 3 days to predict the 4th one. Since it behaves reasonably well, what does that tell you about the data? What else can you infer about the data if you look into the parameters that your model has?
(You can apply this same reasoning for the other models, with what each of them do.)


How to chose one model over another?

(You did not ask this but I'm adding it anyway.)
It depends on your particular case. Sometimes, a worse model is preferable if the blind spot it has is acceptable (e.g., we prefer false positives over false negatives in cancer recognition models). These are different evaluation metrics you can take on your model, and which one to chose really depends on your domain and your use case.
